# While saving the photograph app freezes and takes long time to save in MacOS

Tags: python, macos, opencv, save, photo

Here is my code:

```
    import os
    import cv2
    import uuid
    import time


    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    POZ_Dosya = os.path.join("veriler", "pozitif")
    NEG_Dosya = os.path.join("veriler", "negatif")
    Temel_Dosya = os.path.join("veriler", "temel")
    os.makedirs(POZ_Dosya, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(NEG_Dosya, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(Temel_Dosya, exist_ok=True)

    target_size = 250

    while camera.isOpened():
        ret, frame = camera.read()

        scale_percent = 33 
        width = int(frame.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
        height = int(frame.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
        dim = (width, height)
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

        height, width, _ = frame.shape

        start_row = max(0, int((height - target_size) / 2))
        end_row = min(height, start_row + target_size)
        start_col = max(0, int((width - target_size) / 2))
        end_col = min(width, start_col + target_size)

        frame = frame[start_row:end_row, start_col:end_col, :]
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (target_size, target_size))
        cv2.imshow("a", frame)
        
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("a"):
            time.sleep(10)
            imagename = os.path.join(Temel_Dosya, '{}.jpg'.format(uuid.uuid1()))
            cv2.imwrite(imagename, frame)
        
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("p"):
            pass
        
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
        
    camera.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[My computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMiLr.png)

How can I solve this.

Thanks in advance.

I was trying to take lots of photos for a dataset but it freezes when saving and takes long time to save. I have added

```
 "editor.formatOnSave": false,
 "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": "never"
```

to my setting.js on VS code still it keeps contuing

Comment: Do you know what `time.sleep(10)` does? Why are you calling that function prior to writing the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the freezing issue might be related to the fact that you're using `cv2.imshow` and `cv2.waitKey` inside a loop, and the key event handling might be causing delays. Additionally, the `time.sleep(10)` after saving an image could be contributing to the freezing.

Here are a few suggestions to optimize and potentially solve the freezing issue:

1. **Move `cv2.imshow` outside the loop:**
   Display the image outside the loop to reduce the overhead of updating the display in every iteration.

   ```py
   while camera.isOpened():
       # ... (your existing code)
       cv2.imshow("a", frame)
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   ```
2. **Avoid multiple `cv2.waitKey` calls:**
   Combine your key event checks to a single `cv2.waitKey` call to prevent redundant checks.

   ```py
   while camera.isOpened():
       # ... (your existing code)
       key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
       if key == ord("a"):
           time.sleep(10)
           imagename = os.path.join(Temel_Dosya, '{}.jpg'.format(uuid.uuid1()))
           cv2.imwrite(imagename, frame)
       elif key == ord("p"):
           pass
       elif key == ord("q"):
           break
       cv2.imshow("a", frame)
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   ```
3. **Check for key events only when necessary:**
   Instead of checking for key events in every iteration, you can move the key event handling to specific conditions where you want to capture an image.

   ```py
   while camera.isOpened():
       # ... (your existing code)
       cv2.imshow("a", frame)

       key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
       if key == ord("a"):
           time.sleep(10)
           imagename = os.path.join(Temel_Dosya, '{}.jpg'.format(uuid.uuid1()))
           cv2.imwrite(imagename, frame)
       elif key == ord("q"):
           break

   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   ```

Make sure to test these changes and see if the freezing issue persists. If the problem continues, you may need to explore more specific profiling and debugging techniques to identify the bottleneck in your code.

Comment: The problem is the `time.sleep(10)`, since it blocks for 10 seconds. Generally (I'd expect MacOS to be no different) you need to run `cv2.waitKey` periodically (as in multiple times per second), since that's what processes the GUI events. If nothing processes the GUI events for 10 seconds, it will stop responding (aka freeze) -- no repaints will be done in the window, etc.

Comment: As for the suggestions: #1 is irrelevant (`imshow` hardly presents a meaningful overhead, and showing all the frames is the intent here). #2 is meaningful, but the explanation misses the point, and it wouldn't cause freezing either. The problem with multiple `waitKey`s is that hitting the proper key at the right time becomes a gamble. (key events are consumed by each call). #3 is also irrelevant (you saved what, one comparison?)

Comment: Honestly, the more I read into this, the more it looks like something an AI bot would produce, and looking at your only other answer, I'm even more confident that's the case. Flagging for moderator attention.